# How to prove that the following process is a Martingale using Ito's formula?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I am asked to prove that $Y_t$ is a martingale where $Y_t=\exp\left(\int_0^tf(s)\,dW_s-1/2\int_0^tf(s)^2\,dt\right)$ using Ito's formula.

After applying Ito's formula (I hope I made no mistake) I get $dY_t= Y_t \, dM_t$ where $M_t=\int_0^tf(s) \, dW_s$

What to do next ?

Comment: Note that stochastic integrals with respect to martingales are (local) martingales.

Comment: Well, then $dM_t=f(t)dW_t$ hence $dY_t=Y_tf(t)dW_t$, qed.

Comment: Chapter 4 of Oksendal , Stochastic differential equations, 2000, answers this question (proces $Y_t$ and it's Ito formula is even used in the proof of the Ito representation theorem and that it is a martingale see exercises 4.12 and 4.13)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP solved the problem. There is nothing to do next.

Answer (score 0):

Maye does this work :  We have $Y_t=\int_0^tY_sf(s)dW_s$ where W is a brownian motion, so $Y_t$ is a Wiener(ito) integral and thus it is a martingale